# PowerView with SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, powerview

Is it required to have sharepoint server for working with PowerView in SSRS? I have SQL Server with MSBI 2012. I am BI developer. I wanted to explore with power view. I got an addon for SSRS from microsoft portal (PivotViewer Extension for Reporting Services – CTP2). But relese notes says that it needs Share Point.

I got an other link to download (Microsoft SQL Server 2012 With Power View For Multidimensional Models CTP) this is a 2 GB file and sounds like independent of sharepoint. I am confused. Please help me in understing the working of PowerView with SSRS. Many Thnaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharepoint server is required for Power View in SSRS. Please check this document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231687.aspx
Power View also comes in Excel 2012 (see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/power-view-explore-visualize-and-present-your-data-HA102835634.aspx ). It can access data within worksheets as well as external data sources and has same visualization capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an ebook explaining all SSRS models available for SQL Server 2012, with walkthroughs

http://www.scribd.com/doc/102370834/SQL-Server-2012-Tutorials-Reporting-Services

Answer (score 0):

Power View is now available through Excel 2013 Professional Plus.

You can connect to external data source or use the internal PowerPivot model.

[image: Power View in the Excel Insert ribbon]

Answer (score 0):

You can now use Power BI in SSRS to create a report such as 'Power View' reports.

[image]

A technical Preview of Power BI reports in SQL Server Reporting Services released in January 2017. You can now download the software and install it on your own on-premises VM or server. In the latter case, you’ll need:

- Your own VM or server (not one in production use)
- Windows Server 2012 or later (or Windows 8 or later)
- .NET Framework 4.5.2 or later SQL
- Server Database Engine (2008 or later), to store the report server
  database
- SQL Server Analysis Services (2012 SP1 CU4 or later), to
  store your data models

For more details, Please refer to below link:
[Power BI reports in SQL Server Reporting Services: January 2017 Technical Preview now available](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/01/17/power-bi-reports-in-sql-server-reporting-services-january-2017-technical-preview-now-available/)